# Regular expression in code coverage settings

Tags: regex, code-coverage, vs-unit-testing-framework

I need to filter out some modules from the code coverage. I'm using the following regular expression:

```
<ModulePath>.*\.i.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
```

to exclude the following assemblies: `assembly.iwhatever.dll`

but it does not work. Can anybody help me with the regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the `$` anchor after `dll` you can try the following :

```
<ModulePath>(.*\.i.*\.dll)</ModulePath>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ0zC6/1)

*Note* that using anchors is depend on you text!

Comment: I need the '$' to indicate that the '.dll' should be at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this inside an `<Exclude>` tag:

```
<Exclude>
  <!-- But exclude some assemblies: -->
  <ModulePath>[^.]*\.i.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
</Exclude>
```

See more about that on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx) and the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qY6lI6/1) that will only exclude DLLs that have `i` after the first `.`.

Comment: Your expression does not help me... for some reason the file is not excluded. I guess the problem is not the expression itself but something else...

Comment: Are you sure? Try `<ModulePath>^[^.]*\.i.*\.dll$</ModulePath>` with the `^` anchor. I just do not know what DLLs you have, perhaps, we need to be more precise. BTW, did you `Add the ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute to your test class.`? Is the `<Exclude>` inside `<ModulePaths>` tag?

Comment: Also, have a look at `In Visual Studio 2010, the .testsettings file applies only to unit tests based on the MSTest framework. From Visual Studio 2012, the testing tools apply not only to MSTest, but also other frameworks such as NUnit and xUnit.net. The .testsettings file will not work with these. The .runsettings file is designed to customize the test tools in a way that works with all testing frameworks.`.